# Best practice for timeseries prediction with help of indicators

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I would like to predict values (e.g. transport volumes). As input data I have the volumes from the last two years. I already did some timeseries prediction on those values basically following the instruction on [Basics of Time Series Prediction](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-prediction/) and [Techniques for Time Series Prediction](https://iq.opengenus.org/time-series-prediction-techniques/).

I now would like to go a step further and include some indicators (e.g. economic indicators) in the prediction to see if this will increase the accuracy of the predictions.

What is the right approach to do so? Looking around I found this [Post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476806/forecast-based-on-indicators), basically describing the same usecase. Unfortunately it got no responses.

One approach might be to do a "simple" prediction based on a model with the current volume and indicators as features and the future volume as label. But I then would loose the timeseries, the connection between the single data points so to say.

Do you have experience with such predictions? What did work in your case? Please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

> One approach might be to do a "simple" prediction based on a model
> with the current volume and indicators as features and the future
> volume as label. But I then would loose the timeseries, the connection
> between the single data points so to say.

In this case a common solution is to include N 'lagging' values (i.e. volumes for N previous periods) as features for every observation, in addition to some indicator value features. This allows using pretty much any regression model for time series forecasting. Just make sure there's no data leakage of the 'future' values when calculating your indicators.

Comment: Thanks, I already thought about that as well, but was unsure about the number of inputs/lagging values per observation. I will work on an implementation of this approach and hopefully come back with a positive result.